# Create tree from the ids of LIs in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create valid JSON from the id's of li's in a nested unordered list:  e.g here is an example list.  Just to clarify I do NOT want to create the UL list, but the JSON from the li id's

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li id="p1">1234</li>
    <li id="p2">1234
        <ul>
            <li id="s1">sdfg</li>
            <li id="s2">sdfg
                <ul>
                    <li id="sq1">sdfg</li>
                    <li id="sq2">sdfg</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="p6">1234</li>
    <li id="p8">1234</li>
</ul>
```

The JSON should read something like this:

```
[
  {
    "item": "p1"
  },
  {
    "item": "p2",
    "data": [
      {
        "item": "s1"
      },
      {
        "item": "s2",
        "data": [
          {
            "item": "sq1"
          },
          {
            "item": "sq2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": "p6"
  },
  {
    "item": "p8"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to create it like this:

```
let $arr = []
document.querySelectorAll("ul.list li").forEach($li => {
  if ($li.querySelector("ul:first-of-type")) {
    let $data = [];
    $li.querySelectorAll("ul:first-of-type li").forEach($li1 => {
      $data.push({ "item": $li1.id })
    })
    $arr.push({ "item": $li.id, "data": $data })
  } else {
    $arr.push({ "item": $li.id })
  }
})
```

But it's not creating the correct JSON - any clues / help that creates the correct JSON much appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: create an Object (Array's are Object's too), use `JSON.stringify` ... done, valid JSON

Comment: You're missing your nested `ul` elements as nodes in your tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to recurse through the tree to build your object, then `JSON.stringify`. Here using a simple recursive loop, but you could also look at [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) which is made for traversing the DOM.

```js
function buildTree(parent) {
  let result = [];
  for (const child of parent.children) {
    const data = buildTree(child);
    if (child.id === '') {
      result = data;
    } else {
      result.push({ item: child.id, ...(data.length ? { data } : {}) });
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const tree = buildTree(document.querySelector('.list'));

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li id="p1">1234</li>
    <li id="p2">1234
        <ul>
            <li id="s1">sdfg</li>
            <li id="s2">sdfg
                <ul>
                    <li id="sq1">sdfg</li>
                    <li id="sq2">sdfg</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="p6">1234</li>
    <li id="p8">1234</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Edited to better match your expected output. (skipping elements with no `id` and only adding `data` property to those elements with children)